# Full height tailwind <main> section

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="min-h-screen bg-red-100 flex flex-col">
    <nav class="h-16 bg-yellow-100">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
            <p>Nav goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main class="flex-grow">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto bg-white">
            <div>Content goes here</div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

On a large screen, I have a yellow `nav` the full width, with a container (`max-w-7xl`) centered within it.

The `<main>` element takes up the remaining screen space, and has a container with a white background at the top, center.

My question is, how do I get the white element (a `div`), to take up the remaining height?  I tried wrapping it in its own column flex container, and telling the white `div` to grow.  That worked, except that the width of the white `div` then shrinks to its minimum.

Comment: Do you want the main section will 100% height and its color to be white?

Answer (score 1):

I tried and this code worked correctly

```
<main class="flex flex-grow">
   <div class="bg-white flex-1">
       <div>Content goes here</div>
   </div>
</main>
```